# Unity. How to interpolate multiple sounds depending on float value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, interpolation

So, there is a variable number of car engine sounds (array). I would like to make the sounds smoothly flow from one to the other, depending on the engine RPM (a number from 0 to 1, where 0 = 0 RPM, 1 = for example 7000), like the way the FMOD program does it.

I have already written the basis of the script, but I have stalled on the calculations of the transitions. I hope someone can give me the magic formula…

I have attached a picture and my code for better understanding.

[image]

```
public class Car_Audio : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CarController carController;

    [SerializeField] private AudioClip[] engineRPMSoundClips;

    [SerializeField, Range(0.35f, 0.75f)] private float minEngineVolume = 0.65f;
    [SerializeField, Range(0.75f, 1)] private float maxEngineVolume = 1;

    [HideInInspector] public List<AudioSource> engineRPMSoundSources;

    private float acceleration;

    private float verticalInput;
    private float currRPM;
    private float maxRPM;
    private int currGear;
    private bool isGearShifting;
    private bool isBraking;

    private void Start()
    {
        carController = FindObjectOfType<CarController>();
        maxRPM = carController.maxRPM;

        for (int i = 0; i < engineRPMSoundClips.Length; i++)
        {
            AudioSource tempSource = EngineAudioSourceSetUp(engineRPMSoundClips[i]);
            engineRPMSoundSources.Add(tempSource);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        verticalInput = carController.verticalInput;
        currRPM = carController.currRPM;
        currGear = carController.currGear;
        isGearShifting = carController.isGearShifting;
        isBraking = carController.isBraking;

        if (verticalInput != 0 && !isGearShifting && !isBraking) acceleration = Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Clamp(verticalInput, minEngineVolume, maxEngineVolume));
        else acceleration = Mathf.Lerp(acceleration, minEngineVolume / 2, 0.1f);

        float currEngineRPMPosition = Mathf.Clamp(currRPM / maxRPM, 0, 1);

        foreach (AudioSource audSrc in engineRPMSoundSources)
        {
           audSrc.volume = ...
        }
    }

    private AudioSource EngineAudioSourceSetUp(AudioClip clip)
    {
        AudioSource source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        source.clip = clip;
        source.volume = 0;
        source.spatialBlend = 1;
        source.loop = true;
        source.dopplerLevel = 0;
        source.time = Random.Range(0f, clip.length);
        source.minDistance = 50;
        source.maxDistance = 250;
        source.Play();
        return source;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like a problem of calculating a percentage with an offset. I find the easiest way to handle this is to say:

```
var t = (value - min) / (max - min);
```

The t value is the percentage. It is however unclamped, so you have to handle that afterwards.

If you stored the minimum and maximum RPM value of each clip you could easily calculate what the current t value would be for a clip, based on a given RPM.

Here's a way this class could look:

```
private class RPMClip
{
    public float min, max;
    public AudioClip clip;

    public RPMClip(AudioClip clip, float min, float max)
    {
        this.clip = clip;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public float GetValue(float rpm)
    {
        if (max == min) return 0;
        var t = (rpm - min) / (max - min);
        return Mathf.Clamp01(t);
    }
}
```

With the GetValue method you give it the current RPM, and it will give you a value between 0 and 1 based on its min and max value.

For instance if you give it a min of 50, and a max of 150, then `GetValue(100)` will give you `0.5`

You can then apply this value to a curve that defines how much volume it should have.

Comment: Hmm. It might work. I'll try to fit it to my task. Thank you)